# Cannot Subscript Error on Deeply Nested Data Structure

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a deeply nested array of dictionaries like this:

```
func markAllBooksAsUnread() {

    for (cat, catArray) in bookage.setless {
        for (gen, genArray) in catArray {
            for (foc, focArray) in genArray {
                for dict in focArray {
                    bookage.setless[cat]![gen]![foc]![dict]["read"] = "no"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code, which looks right to me, is producing the error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type Array<Dictionary<String, String>> with an index of type 'Dictionary<String, String>'
```

With the carrot under the 'd' in [dict].  The structure of the bookage.setless array is:

```
var setless = [String : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>>]()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict` is a dictionary, you can't use it as index. Try this:

```
for (cat, catArray) in bookage.setless {
    for (gen, genArray) in catArray {
        for (foc, focArray) in genArray {
            for i in focArray.indices {
                bookage.setless[cat]![gen]![foc]![i]["read"] = "no"
            }
        }
    }
}
```